# What are the applications of Solr in Big Data?

Tags: bigdata

Why is solr used in Big Data?

What is it's purpose?

Comment: @SeanOwen I have edited the question details.  Seems like it appears clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr is a highly scalable, fault tolerant search server.

So, you can store files in the form of JSON, XML, CSV or binary over HTTP.
And you can query it via **GET** and receive JSON, XML, CSV and binary results. It also has a distributed architecture for the purpose, which is the primary and most important concept in Big Data and it's handling.

So, as it is highly scalable and fault tolerant for high traffic and huge documents, it is a choice for a reliable search engine for huge documents, or in short **Big Data**.

Comment: Thank you..!!! Is solr is only related to query?

Comment: Yes, Solr is only for search and navigation.

Comment: What do you mean by **current Trend**?  Can you explain or elaborate?

Comment: Is Solr used in current Technologies?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Here are some links which would prove it: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/PublicServers,  http://www.quora.com/Which-major-companies-are-using-Solr-for-search

And there are a lot of wrappers and libraries for using Solr with some of the top programming languages out there (like Python, etc).

Comment: Glad that it helped.  Do accept the answer, so that future viewers would get benefitted.